# sorting and cleaning of data

Tags: python-3.x, data-cleaning, columnsorting

I am new to this group and I am a budding python programmer. I am stuck with a small assignment which I have to finish. Below are the issues I am facing. Also please see the code which I have written.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv("/Users/nancy/Desktop/sample.csv")
a = data["A"]
b = a.str.replace("First year"," ")
c = b.str.replace("First year"," ")
print (c)
data.to_csv("/Users/nancy/Desktop/sample1.csv")
```

I would like to sort column named X and Y in alphabetical order with column Y having same corresponding values in column in A,B,C,D. 
I want to replace "First year" in column A and column C with blank space.

I am able to replace it with blank space. However, I am not able to write the new data to new csv file.
I want to replace “First and current year” in column A and column C with blank space and also reproduce same data in column B and D

Regards,
Nancy

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. None of your code deals with sorting. What have you tried so far? Please also provide a **[mcve]**. We have no access to `sample.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `data.sort_values("your_column")`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
data["A"] = data["A"].str.replace("First year and current year"," ")
data["A"] = data["A"].str.replace("First year"," ")
data["C"] = data["C"].str.replace("First year and current year"," ")
data["C"] = data["C"].str.replace("First year"," ")
#print (data)
#print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------")
sorted_data = data.sort_values('Y')
#print(sorted_data)
sorted_data.to_csv("sample1.csv",index = False)
```

You can check this http://cmdlinetips.com/2018/02/how-to-sort-pandas-dataframe-by-columns-and-row/ to see more examples.

Comment: This was really helpful and worked as I expected. I need one more help.  I want to replace same data in column B and column D from column A and column C respectively whenever the text “First and current year” presents. Please help.

Comment: I also wanted to split the column X in to two columns. First column with values before , and second column with values after ,(comma). I have done my research on this and  I was not able to do this, But I am able to add a new column with existing data.

Comment: I tried using data['X'] = data['X'].str.split(',', expand= True) to split the column. But he values after comma got deleted

Comment: You can loop through the dataframe to achieve this.

Comment: For splitting, this walk around may help 
`data['X1']=data['X'].str.split(',').str[0]
data['X2']=data['X'].str.split(',').str[1]
data.drop('X', axis=1, inplace=True)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please help me with first comment?

Comment: data['B'] = data['A'].where(data['A']== "First and current laws:"), data['B']) /// I tried using this code. But the problem is I can only copy when the data is exactly "First and current laws:" The action I wanted to perform is, I wanted to copy if the cell contains this string "First and current laws:"